# Download file from Dropbox to local android Java

Tags: java, android, download, local-storage, dropbox

I spent some days on this code without finding the solution. Could you help me please?

I want to download a file from a Dropbox account to the application storage (local memory). When I open the file for the first time, the application crashes then when I restart the application, the file can be open from the local memory.

```
private void ImportDB(String nameDB)
  {
          try {
              File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

                  //Local file
                  String backupDBPath = "//data//[Package name]//databases//"+nameDB;
                  File backupDB = new File(data, backupDBPath);

                  //Dropbox file                      
                  DbxPath testPath = new DbxPath(DbxPath.ROOT, nameDB);
                  DbxFileSystem dbxFs = DbxFileSystem.forAccount(mDbxAcctMgr.getLinkedAccount());


                  DbxFile testFile = dbxFs.open(testPath);

                    FileChannel src = testFile.getReadStream().getChannel();
                    FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();

                     //Transfert to local
                      dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());

                      //close
                      src.close();
                      dst.close();
                      testFile.close();
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {

          }
  }
```

I guess it is a question of synchronization: the file is not yet copied when I try to open it. I tried this code for waiting the file but it doesn't work, the program stays in the while loop:

```
Thread mThread = new Thread()
            {
            @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
            public void run()
            {
                    //open the local file
                    File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
                    String currentDBPath = "//data//[Package name]//databases//"+nameFileDB";
                    File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);

                    // test when the file is downloaded
                    while (!currentDB.exists())
                    {
                        Log.i("tag", "In loop");

                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    //CODE TO OPEN THE FILE HERE

                }
            }
            };
            mThread.start();
```

Any idea???

Comment: Please edit your question and include the stack trace for the exception from logcat.

Comment: `String backupDBPath = "//data//[Package name]//databases//"+nameDB;` is actually `String backupDBPath = "/data/data/[Package name]/databases/" + nameDB;` You missed one **/data**... Same here: `String currentDBPath = "//data//[Package name]//databases//"+nameFileDB";`

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it is not a problem of path because when I restart the application (after a first crash), it can open the files from the local memory with this path://data//[Package name]//databases//"+nameDB

Comment: Actually to be rigorous, we can change //data//[Package name]//databases//"+nameFileDB" by getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath(nameDB).getPath()

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to achieve your goal.

- Download file from Dropbox in [doInBackground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground(Params...)).
- [onPostExecute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)) will be called when the file download is completed.

Comment: Thank you Wonil for your answer but I already tried the AsyncTask and I have the same problem. I guess when the download from Dropbox is ordered, the program goes to the onPostExecute but it doesn't mean that the downloading is finished. I think I must have a listener on when the file is downloaded to the local memory. I a going to search that.